# Shadow appearing on Android status bar

Tags: android, statusbar

I've been trying to make the status bar on phones with Android version 5.0+ translucent, but to no avail. It works, but there's a shadow on it.

Here's my styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Here's my styles.xml (v21):

```
<resources>>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Any idea how I'm supposed to fix this problem? I tried calling setVerticalFadingEdgeEnable(false) on the CoordinatorLayout and the AppBarLayout, but the shadow still appears on the status bar. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

This shadow is part of `windowContentOverlay` on APIs below `LOLLIPOP` (on LOLLIPOP it's @null).

When you work with Toolbar widget the toolbar isn't part of window decor anymore so the shadow starts at the top of the window over the toolbar instead of below it (so you want the windowContentOverlay to be @null). Additionally you need to add an extra empty View below the `toolbar pre-LOLLIPOP` with its background set to a vertical shadow drawable (`8dp tall gradient` from `#20000000` to `#00000000` works best). On `LOLLIPOP` you can set `8dp elevation` on the toolbar instead.

For more detail visit [Toolbar's shadow on status bar for Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891756/toolbars-shadow-on-status-bar-for-lollipop/34891871#34891871)

Comment: I set the windowContentOverlay to @null and set 0dp elevation on the toolbar. It still displays the shadow.

Comment: visit this for more .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575197/no-shadow-by-default-on-toolbar/31026359#31026359